# $(X,Z) \sim (Y,Z) \implies X \sim Y$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, examples-counterexamples

Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables such that the random vectors $(X,Z)$ and $(Y,Z)$ have the same law. Is it true that $X$ and $Y$ have the same law ?

I can't find a counterexample to it but I can't see why would it hold neither. The assumption says that $$\mathbb P(X\leq x, Z\leq z)=\mathbb P(Y\leq x, Z\leq z) $$

If $X$ and $Y$ were independent from $Z$ then we have $\mathbb P(X\leq x)=\mathbb P(Y\leq x) $. However, if they are not independent I can't see what formal argument says that $X$ and $Y$ have the same law. Is there a counterexample I am not thinking of ?

Comment: There are a few viable arguments, the most basic being $$\Bbb P\left[X\le \alpha\right]=\Bbb P\left[(X,Z)\in (-\infty,\alpha]\times \Bbb R\right]=\Bbb P\left[(Y,Z)\in (-\infty,\alpha]\times \Bbb R\right]=\Bbb P\left[Y\le \alpha\right]$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution

Comment: Please try not to have titles comprised entirely of $\rm\LaTeX$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In fact the first comment gives a nice and easy argument.
@Shaun, mathematically speaking, no, my title was not entirely in Latex since the "?" was outside the latex expression :) but ok I'll remember for next time